# Не получается создать отдельные элементы в DOM через JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Здравствуй, стэковерфлоу. Пытаюсь сделать ради тренировки некое подобие Trello. Пытаюсь добиться того, чтобы можно было создавать таблички, а в них внутрь вводить ту-ду листы. Но созданные через дж-с кнопки засчитываются за одинаковую, а не за разные. Пробовал добавлять кнопки через appendChild и тоже ничего не вышло. Очевидно понимаю, что косяк именно в кривом методе вставки кнопок и в "аккордеоне", но решения не вижу.

```js
// Creating new table
function cnt() {
  if ($(".cnt input").val() !== "") {
    $(".tables").append("<button>" + $(".cnt input").val() + "</button>" + "<br />");
    $(".cnt input").val("");
  }
}

//Creating subtables in a table
function subcnt() {
  if ($(".panel input").val() !== "") {
    $(".panel").append($(".panel input").val() + "<br />");
    $(".panel input").val("");
  }
}

// Launching cnt with either mouseclick or Enter-only input
$(".cnt button").on("click", function() {
  cnt();
});

$(".cnt input").on("keypress", function() {
  if (event.key == "Enter") {
    cnt();
  }
});

$(".panel input").on("keypress", function() {
  if (event.key == "Enter") {
    subcnt();
  }
});

//Trying to add under each table an working accordion
// tb = tables, don't want to use faceless i, j or k
let acc = $('.tables');
for (let tb = 0; tb < acc.length; tb++) {
  acc[tb].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
  };
}
```

```css
.tables button.active,
.tables button:hover {
  background-color: #9c66cf
}

div.panel {
  display: none;
}

div.panel.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cnt">
  <!--create new table-->
  <input type="text">
  <button>Create new table</button>
</div>

<div class="tables">
  <!--New tables will appear here-->
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <!--Here will be inner containtment-->
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: в каком именно месте приведенного кода проблема?

Comment: В аппенде кнопок. Мне нужно чтобы под разынми кнопками можно было писать разные вещи. При нынешнем состоянии кода при нажатии на любую из новосозданных кнопок открывается один и тот же блок panels. А мне надо, чтобы под каждой из новых кнопок было свое поле ввода и свой текст.  Мне нужно каким-то образом разделить кнопки, и вот я не понимаю как

Comment: в смысле "за одинаковые"? одинаковые действия при нажатии?

Comment: Угу, выше откомментил. При нажатии на любую из новосозданных кнопок открывается единый блок panels. А я хочу, чтобы под каждой кнопкой этот блок был индивидуальный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что обработчик навешивается не на кнопку, а на таблицу. Поэтому всегда открывается панель непосредственно за таблицей.

В качестве решения может быть либо делегирование обработчика:

```
$('.tables').on('click','button',function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

либо добавление обработчика непосредственно при создании кнопки.

Однако в этом случае нужно либо менять разметку, либо менять код обработчика, для определения нужного блока для показа.

Comment: Спасибо, определенный прогресс пошел.